# Bootstrap dropdown menu – stay open if search bar is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a customized bootstrap dropdown menu that opens and closes on hover (which I have working), but also stays open if the search bar is focused in the Events dropdown menu until it loses focus or the users clicks away from the dropdown.

Here is my js code:

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
 $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').show(); $(this).addClass('open'); },
 function() { 
    $("#search-query").focusin(function() {
        $('.events').addClass('search-active'); 
    });
    if ($('.events').hasClass('search-active')) {
        return;
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').hide(); $(this).removeClass('open'); 
    }
 });
```

Here is a codepen so you can see the rest of my code: http://codepen.io/webinsation/pen/bfDsB

I have tried several different ways to solve this using jquery’s is(':focus') selector with no results.

I appreciate any help or ideas you may have.
Thanks,
– Caleb

Comment: when I click on the search bar and moved my mouse away it stayed open. And when I clicked away it went away.

Comment: Try "bootply" as an alternative to jsfiddle (in the future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:focus` to find if the search box has focus in the second `hover` function, without any need to give things additional events. `.size()` will return 1 if it has focus and 0 otherwise, and then the `!` casts those to true and false, respectively, before negating. Then in the first hover function, check to make sure there are no currently open menus before opening.

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  if (!$(".dropdown-menu:visible").size()) {
     $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').show(); $(this).addClass('open');
   }
  },
 function() { 
   if (!$(".navbar-search input:focus").size()) {
     $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').hide(); $(this).removeClass('open'); 
   }
 });
```

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aymIF)

Comment: Thanks for your input @Joe! The only problem now is that my other menus will still open(and get stuck open) if they are hovered when the search-bar(input) has focus. I need to make it so that the other menus cannot be opened unless they are clicked on when the search-bar is focused.

Comment: Yep, I should've included that before, sorry. I've updated it to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, only problem is that your fix broke the hover behavior on my actual site. what you really need is to check that the .events dropdown menu is not visible before showing other menus. If you don’t mind I will edit your answer with the final code and then mark it as answered.

Comment: Looks like your edit was rejected, probably because the current answer solves the problem as it was stated in the question. It works the same in CodePen with or without the `.events`.

Comment: Yes, works the same in codepen, but in production things are messed up. It needs to be ".events .dropdown-menu:visible". Anyways, thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

I'll have my try.

I've used the `hover()` function and it's callback.

```
function () {
    if (!$("#search-query").is(':focus')){
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    } else if ( !$( '.events' ).is( ':hover' ) ) {
        $("#search-query").blur();
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
});
```

on hover it's pretty much the same, You can set it back to closest as it was before.

On the callback (no hover) I check if not the `.events` gets hovered (so it'll show each of the other menu items drop down menus and also hiding the `.events` menu when hover removed. (you can set it to click if you want).

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVJWz/2/), Hope it assists.

Comment: Thanks for answering Shahar, but the answer above is what I was looking for. Appreciate your help.